# why react hook init before redux props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

this is some kind of code so be gentle :D

i have some page that use react hooks and redux and the redux state work
i checked it it load data. the scenario is i have page that load input boxes from redux thunk and save the changes with hooks and redux thunk

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const { reduxProp } = props

    const [t1, setT1] = useState('')
    
    useEffect( () => {
        reduxActionLoadData // t1 , t2 data
        setT1(reduxProp.t1)
        setT2(reduxProp.t2)
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
           <input value={t1} onChange={ (e) => { setT1(e.target.value) } />
           <input value={t2} onChange={ (e) => { setT2(e.target.value) } />
        </div>
     )
}

const mapStateToProp = (state) => (
{
    reduxProp: state.reduxProp
})

const mapDispatchToProp = (dispatch) => (
{
    reduxActionLoadData = connectActionCreators(reduxActionLoadDataAction, dispatch)
})

export default const connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

when i check props it is loaded, redux state is loaded too
but hooks init with empty value
i try to init them with reduxProp.t1, reduxProp.t2 no luck there too
the thing is when i run app it works fine but when i refresh the page it fails
and sometimg it fails when i run app too
i try to use loading state and do stuff after loading = true no luck the either

Comment: You are not showing where `t2` is coming from. Are you using the legacy `connect` api somwhere? Please provide *all* relevant code here.

Comment: yup i use connect api here to connect mapStateToProp and mapDispatchToProp

Answer (score 2):

For one, your `mapDispatchToProp` currently does not seem to do anything, since with the `=` it will be parsed as a method body, not as an object - so you are not connecting your actions at all. It should look more like this:

```js
const mapDispatchToProp = (dispatch) => (
{
    reduxActionLoadData: connectActionCreators(reduxActionLoadDataAction, dispatch)
})
```

Then you *should* instead be using the map object notation:

```js
const mapDispatchToProp = {
    reduxActionLoadData: reduxActionLoadDataAction
}
```

and the you also have to actually use that in your component:

```js
    useEffect( () => {
        props.reduxActionLoadData()
    },[])
```

That will still create an asynchronous effect, so `reduxProp.t1` will not change immediately.
You will probably have to update those later in a separate `useEffect`.

```js
    useEffect( () => {
        setT1(reduxProp.t1)
    },[reduxProp.t1])
```

All that said, **there is no reason to use `connect` at all**, since you could also use the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks. `connect` is a legacy api that you really only need to use with legacy class components.

Generally I would assume that you are right now learning a very outdated style of Redux by following an outdated tutorial. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPE constants, hand-written action creators, immutable reducer logic or connect - and it is maybe 1/4 of the code of old-style Redux.
Please follow the official Redux tutorial for an understanding of mondern Redux. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: the = is mistype here and my code work with :, i get the usage of several useEffect hooks, and as soon as i read your comment that said legacy connect, i jump on and read about the new stuff and realized i learn the outdated version so i will rewrite all my stuff with new hooks and see what happens because using so many useEffects seems not good at all, thank you for taking time and answer my question

Comment: Please note that `connect` vs hooks is really just the tip of the iceberg - most of Redux will be completely different, so I recommend going by the tutorial above.